Grammar pattern "show someone/something + V-ed" in "The picture shows a family gathered around a kitchen table."
I suspect that the following sentence is NOT grammatically correct:

The picture shows a family gathered around a kitchen table.

Because, I only see the pattern "show someone/something + adv./prep." not "show someone/something + V-ed".
However, it was found in a popular Oxford Advanced's Learner Dictionary here in section the Express Yourself under sense 2.
If it's grammatically correct, then how should I interpret the sentence in this case?

'Gathered' is the past participle of the verb 'gather' (here used as an adjective). The sentence is perfectly grammatically correct.

It's a grammatically correct sentence. It means In the picture we can see a family, and the family is gathered around the kitchen table.

It’s a perfectly fine English sentence. Compare it to She went to the hospital for a broken toe. Here, a broken toe means a toe that was or had been broken. In your sentence, the picture shows a family that is (or that has) gathered around the table.
Another example is the aphorism, A watched pot never boils, in which the grammatical subject refers to a pot that is being watched.
